# Each function doesn't work. Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'll be greatfull if anyone can correct  me where I'm wrong.
 It's too simple but just don't get it where I'm wrong.  It  should color also third #one div yellow but it doesn't..

```js
if ($('#main #main-two #one').not(':first-child') && ($('#one img').attr('src') == 'http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg')) {
  $('#one').each(function() {
    $('#one').css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
};
```

```css
#one {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-two">
    <div id="one">
    </div>
    <div id="one">
      <img src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="one">
      <img src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="one">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nucb6nko/1/

Comment: Thank you Crowder, that was really helpfull , specially for beginner as me.

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: I agree with you, will ask properly next time :)

Comment: `$(".class-name").each(function(){ $(this).css({"color":"red"}); });`

Answer (score 3):

`id` values **must** be unique in the document. So your `id="one"` elements should probably be `class="one"` instead.

I *think* you're tryhing to turn all of them containing an `img` with the `src` `"http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jp"` yellow. If so, we can do that with a selector using [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and use an attribute value selector within the `:has` clause:

```js
$('#main-two .one:has(img[src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg"])').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```css
.one {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-two">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <img src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <img src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="one">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the "not first-child" part is also important, just add it back to the selector, e.g.:

```
$('#main-two .one:not(:first-child):has(img[src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg"])').css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Finally, note I dropped the `#main` from the selector. In a valid document, there can only be one `#main-two`. The only reason for combining ID selectors is if you want the subordinate one to be ignored if it's not inside the other one, which I suspect isn't the case here.

---

In a comment you've asked:

> ...will this work if I instead .css use addClass('something'); Cause I've tried but nothing happens

Yes, and that's usually the better way to go. Just define your class in your CSS:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

...and then use `.addClass("highlight")` rather than `.css(...)`:

```js
$('#main-two .one:has(img[src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg"])').addClass("highlight");
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.one {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}

img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-two">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <img src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="one">
      <img src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="one">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you alot for responding :) This was really helpfull , and professional so short code .. And forgive me if its not appropriate , then just ignore. But will this work if I instead .css use addClass('something'); Cause I've tried but nothing happens..

Comment: @user2977046: Yes, and in fact I would recommend using a class rather than using `css`. I've added an example at the end of the above.

Comment: Once again , thank you so much , saved me alot of time and I've learned :) Cheers Crowder.

Comment: Good points sir ,please add point that `$(this)` should used with each to loop each element and verey thanks :).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay I've got to ask cause im trying for few hours now. What am I doing wrong.
path in html structure is 

`#mainTwo  > UniqueClass > AnotherUniqueClass which contains 5 .One classes.(containers)
And every One class inside have ClassImag > ClassContent > Img element.` 
What ever I try i can't target , implement your code.

I've tried  
`$('#mainTwo  .UniqueClass .AnotherUniqueClass .one:not(:first-child):has(img[src="http://www.psytrance.pl/artists/atmos/tom.jpg"])').addClass("highlight");`

I can continue adding examples but reached max characters.. And nothing works :/

Comment: @user2977046: Put the structure in a Stack Snippet in the question.